# systemctl hangs when starting sshd, but "/usr/sbin/sshd -D -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config &" works

Tags: centos, ssh, linux-networking, systemd

CentOS 7.
Here's /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenSSH server daemon
Documentation=man:sshd(8) man:sshd_config(5)
After=network.target sshd-keygen.service
Wants=sshd-keygen.service

[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/sshd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $OPTIONS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=42s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Everything that is uncommented in sshd_config:

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
AuthorizedKeysFile.ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
usePAM no # Had to change it to no from yes because the connection was dropping right after successfull auth
X11Forwarding yes
Subsystemsftp/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Anything else I'm happy to provide if needed. Appreciate your help!

Comment: What's in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo there in your `sshd_config`

```
Subsystemsftp/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Should be

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

And this

```
AuthorizedKeysFile.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Should be

```
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Furthermore, do a syntax check of your config

```
sshd -t
```